# Close a modal when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got something like this:

```
<buttn type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> //WORKS GOOD
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_device(event, this)">Add</button>
```

Now I want the whole modal to close at the end of the add_device function. How can I do this?
I've tried

```
$(this).dialog('close');
```

But it doesn't work. Basically I want to do the same thing that I did with mi bttn 'Close' but now I want to do it at the end of this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#modalName').modal('hide');
```

or

```
 $('#button').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Coding
    $('#IDModal').modal('toggle'); //or  $('#IDModal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```